# WiX - Gotchas for Combining COM and .NET components in the same installer

Tags: installation, activex, wix, windows-installer

I have two products that are always installed in tandem. One is an ActiveX exe the other a C# application. I've gotten the ActiveX installer to build and function properly using WiX and I'd really like to combine both into a single installer. I'm feeling just about dangerous enough with WiX to attempt it, but would be interested in any advice (particularly if it is inadvisable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work fine.